# If $A$ and $B$ are $n×n$ matrices such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$ then find the value of $A^{4} + B^{4} - A^{2} -B^ {2} + I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The given question is

> If $A$ and $B$ are $n×n$ matrices such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$, then find the value of $A^{4} + B^{4} - A^{2} -B^ {2} + I$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hint: $$A^2=A(BA)=(AB)A=BA=A$$

Comment: Thanksfor answer so answer is I

Comment: Can you fill in the details?

Comment: Yes i have done it as per your hint A^4 cancels with A^(2) and similarly with B and we are left with I

Comment: Quite right, good job.